# What are the Advantages and disadvantages of AsyncTask in Android framework?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service, virtual-machine

I am learning Android app development from Udacity.com by Google engineers and they said,

"It is not a good idea to use '`AsyncTask`' as it is not attached to an `activity` life cycle. The virtual machine will hold on to the `activity` object as long as the `Asynctask` is running, even after Android has called  onDestroy( ) method for the activity and expect it to be discarded.

If you rotate your phone, the behavior is to destroy the current activity and instantiate a new one. The naive `AsyncTask` implementation now has two `threads` trying to do the same update.  So it is not the best pattern for a potentially very long running background operation , such as fetching from web services. If you leave the app, the `asyncTask` will run as long as as the process is kept alive , but will run at a lower priority, and your process will be the first thing to be killed if the device needs more resources. "

1) If using `AsyncTask` is disadvantageous why was it created? What would have been the design philosophy or the cause to create it in spite of having services(or something similar to achieve same kind of functionality)?

2) What are the situations where `Asynctask` should be used for betterment compared to Services/similar options available in Android?

3) What are the situations/places `Asynctask` should never be used?

Please do not downvote this question. I searched Stackoverflow and I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: This is an excellent question.  Did you find an answer?  I am wondering the same

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't remember. I paused that android project.

Answer (score 8):

Advantages of `AsyncTask`

1. Provides generic solution for all network calls
2. Publish progress to UI while executing.
3. Run Asynchronously
4. Easy to maintain and read.

Problems in `AysncTask`

1. When you rotate your screen, `Activity` gets destroyed, so `AsyncTask` will not have a valid reference to publish data from `onPostExecute()`. In order to retain it, you need to use`setRetainState(true)` if calling from fragment or `onConfigChanges()` if calling from activity method of an activity.
2. If activity gets finished, `AsyncTask` execution will not cancelled automatically, you need to cancel them else they will keep on running in the background.
3. If any `exception` occurs while performing network task, you need to handle them manually.

Whereas `AsycTask`, `Services`, `IntentService`, `Threads` all run on different threads and all serve different purpose.
please read more detail [here](http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html).

So you need to decide when to use which component while performing non UI operations.

Comment: "... When you rotate your screen, Activity gets destroyed, so AsyncTask will not have a valid reference to publish data from onPostExecute() ...". This is not a problem of `AsyncTask`. The problem is with usage you suggest. You should not reference any UI component (e.g. `Activity`) from `AsyncTask`. You should just publish "async task finished event" in your `onPostExecute` and any consumer (an `Activity` for example) may or may not react to this "async task finished event".

Comment: What do you mean by ~"**easy to maintain**"?